# upgrade php 4.2 to 5.2 short open tag syntax error

Tags: php, syntax-error

After upgrade from PHP 4.2 to PHP 5.2

```
<?php $test="hello world";  ?>
<?= $test ?>
```

Returns
    hello world

However, adding comment slash give syntax error

```
<?php $test="hello world";  ?>
<?= //$test ?>
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/phpuser/docroot/lapp/test.php on line 2

Adding comment slash used to work before the upgrade and short_open_tag is enabled in php.ini.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to echo nothing. Why not just comment out using `<!-- <?= $text ?> -->`?

Answer (score 1):

`<?=` is actually equivalent to `<?php echo` so since you basically have `<?php echo //$test ?>` it is looking for a `;` after the echo statement.

I would recommend in this case, using `<?php //echo $test ?>` to get rid of the error.

Comment: I agree with the solution Steve. Error come from codes wrote by other developers during past 10 years. Who knows how many other places that they used this type of coding syntax! I guess there is not easy php.ini tweak that will fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `<?=` (called echo short tag) you are trying to print the value of the following expression. You can't comment it.

You can change your code to

```
<?php $test="hello world";  ?>
<?php echo $test ?>
```

and then comment it:

```
<?php $test="hello world";  ?>
<?php //echo $test ?>
```

Otherwise change `<?=$test?>` to `<?php /*=$test*/?>`
to have the desired effect on your code.

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct.  `<?= //$test ?>` is a syntax error.

```
<?= $test ?>
```

is short for

```
<?php echo $test; ?>
```

So doing

```
<?= //$test ?>
```

is like doing

```
<?php echo //$test; ?>
```

which is clearly a syntax error.